# Converting txt to CSV separated by column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I have a folder with multiply .txt files in the all in the same format, tab separated. I'm trying to convert them to csv's separated by column.

I've tried a simple  `read_file.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Desktop\workspace\Converter\20200923.csv', index=False)`

But it doesn't do the separation I'm looking for. Any suggestions are most welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `sep='\t'`, to tell Pandas it's tab-separated?

Comment: yeah I tried that too and it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: You'll have to post a sample of the format of the data you're working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

for filename in os.listdir('path/to/dir/'):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        df = pd.read_table(filename,sep='\t', header=None) # header=None becuase you didn't say that it was data, if it is data just remove this.
        df.to_csv(f'{filename[:-3]}csv', index=False)
```

Comment: hmm, I seem to be getting  FileNotFoundError when I try this out

Comment: Error occurred at ```df = pd.read_table(filename,sep='\t', header=None) ```  it says ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File 20200926.txt does not exist: '20200926.txt'```

Comment: When I run it in VS code the above error occurred but when I run my .py file in the folder, it seems to work

Comment: Make sure your path has access to the files. If it helped please consider accepting as answer and upvoting. Thanks!